# Azure storage queue max concurrent clients

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage-queues

I have an azure function with a servicebus trigger. I only want x numbers og function instances to run concurrently. This is done with the maxConcurrentCalls=x in the host file. Can this also be achieved with Azure Storage Queues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have installed latest nuget package(e.g `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage`) and try following settings.

1. If the function is on Consumption plan, in Application settings, set `WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT` to `1` to avoid adding host instances. For dedicated App service plan, we could fix instance count to 1.
2. In [host.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#host-json), configure queue batch size according to runtime version(Find in portal, Platform features> Function app settings).

   Runtime ~1

   ```
   {
       "queues": {
         "batchSize": x,
          "newBatchThreshold": 0
       }
   }
   ```

   Runtime ~2

   ```
   { 
     "version":"2.0",
     "extensions": { 
       "queues": { 
         "batchSize": x,
         "newBatchThreshold": 0 
        }
      } 
   }
   ```